# Find top shown view UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, uiview, uiactionsheet, appdelegate, uiwindow

I have the following code that displays an action sheet over the the current visible view (`self.view`)

```
[actionSheet showInView:[self view]];
```

But I'am unable to get a reference to this action sheet in the app delegate by using:

```
UIView *topView = [[self.window subviews] lastObject];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the action sheet is not really added as a subview:

```
- (void)didPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", actionSheet.superview, self.view);
}
```

So one of the ways would be to have a notification posted when the action sheet is displayed; for example:

```
// delegate = self;
- (void)didPresentActionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ActionSheetPresented" object:nil userInfo:@{@"actionSheet": actionSheet}];
}
```

And add an observer for the notification in the `AppDelegate`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(displayed:) name:@"ActionSheetPresented" object:nil];

- (void)displayed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIActionSheet *action = notification.userInfo[@"sheet"];
    NSLog(@"%@", action);
}
```

You might also just leave it is a public property in the view controller and reference in the `AppDelegate` whenever there is `didPresentActionSheet:` delegate API fires.

Comment: but in case adding new action sheets we should care about adding notification, and there is no like automation process. So like in case if we have another developer that want to add new action sheet and he don't care about notification, he just want to present that sheet and for example the when we make push it should work without any issues.

Comment: also actionSheet.superview is nil

Comment: So `actionSheet.superview` is nil implies that it has no super view; therefore if you try to find this action sheet in one of the subviews of `self.view`, you won't achieve anything.

If you are creating a framework, then you can potentially have this as a delegate API call rather than a notification. So instead of posting a notification, refer to your own delegate call. Unfortunately, I don't seem to know a different way.